# Access Query: Joining two queries' data into two columns on a new Query

Tags: ms-access

So, I'm working with inventory for my company. We have the following queries set up in Access:

- QTYs of product forecasted (by forecast date)
- QTYs of product backlogged (by ship date)

What I need is a query that has the following columns headers:

```
 Date  ||  Part Number ||  Forecast QTY  ||  Backlog QTY  ||  Max Value
```

But I'm running into an issue where, because the **Forecast Date** and **Ship Date** are two unrelated dates, my query either shows no results or duplicate results. (No results if I relate the dates, duplicate if not).

In an ideal world I'd have these two initial queries, and the following summary query:

## Backlog Query

```
 Ship Date  ||  Part Number ||  QTY  
 12/1/2017  ||       1      ||  10
 12/2/2017  ||       2      ||  20
```

## Forecast Query

```
 Forecast Date  ||  Part Number ||  QTY  
   12/2/2017    ||       1      ||  20
   12/2/2017    ||       2      ||  30
```

## Final Query

```
    Date    ||  Part Number ||  Forecast QTY  ||  Backlog QTY  ||  Max QTY
 12/1/2017  ||       1      ||        0       ||       10      ||    10
 12/2/2017  ||       1      ||       20       ||        0      ||    20
 12/2/2017  ||       2      ||       30       ||       20      ||    30
```

I already know how to add in the Max QTY column (just a mathematical expression of the prior 2 columns), but I'm hitting a roadblock with the two QTY columns.

Can someone assist with getting this up and running? I've been sitting here for 4 hours now trying a couple things, but ultimately hitting the same roadblock and just blankly staring at my screen.

Answer (score 1):

What you will want to do is create a series of subqueries to answer key questions.

First, a subquery that establishes the dates that are relevant. Let's call it qryDates. This query could be every weekday. Every day. Or it could be the union of all days that show up in your data (that one might end up being, say, a grouped union, producing one record max per "day".)

Then you need your other two subqueries -- the ones that produce backlog and forecast. qryBacklog and qryForecast.

Create a final query that starts by selecting all the days in qryDates and then left join to each of qryBacklog and qryForecast with the left join being by date. At that point you may need to wrap qty nulls with Nz() etc. but you'll then have a query with no duplicate dates but definitely all the answers you are looking for.

I just noted you have part # also -- so make that a two-field join, but you get the idea. If necessary, you may even find it necessary to do a cartesian join between the desired dates and the desired parts (using the resultant data set as the base for your left joins to those qty fields) but this is the way forward. I am guessing you'll want that base query to be the grouped sum of unique combos of date/part... then left join on two fields to the other qty queries.

Comment: I'm not familiar with the SQL format (I've only been working in Design view).  Is there a way to Left Join in design view? Alternatively, can you provide a template for how the SQL should be written as you describe?

Comment: select a.*, b.Whatever, nz(c.Qty, 0) as CQty from (A left join B on A.Date = B.Date and A.PartNo = B.PartNo) left join C on A.Date = C.Date and A.PartNo = C.PartNo .... I scrabbled that quickly, but it's the idea. In the Query builder you right-click the lines to change the join type.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming the ship date and forecast date are related. You want to perform a "full outer join" on the two result tables on both date and part number columns. This will give you a row for each unique date and part number combination even if the data is missing on one of the tables.

For more information on outer join: https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187518%28v=sql.105%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396